# Mongodb repository with spring data findBy query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am writing a query and am trying to figure out if I am using the correct syntax. I have the following code:

```
@Query(value= " persons.personId : ?0 }")
Optional<List<Document>> findFirst50OptionalByPersonsPersonIdOrderByApplicationDateDescIn(List<String> personIdList);
```

the goal is to get the first 50 of an optional list of Documents back who have the specified person object person id attached by an app date descending order.

Is this correct syntax?

Edit:

```
@Document(collection = "appStatus")
@Data
public class Document {

    @Id
    String id;

    List<Person> persons;

}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Person {

    private String personName;
    private String personId;
}
```

Comment: can you show us a sample document from your collection ?

Comment: @Veeram I have added additional info to the question.

Comment: Not sure what error you get.I would try `findOptionalFirst50PersonsPersonIdOrderByApplicationDateDesc(List<String> personIdList);`. Get rid of query annotation.Cant mix and match.

Comment: @Veeram was getting a json parse exception. I want both so I can easily specify the fields that come back without having to extend or write an implementation